# How should I use v-model and v-on:change for an input select correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

So my searches on this topic are coming back with various GitHub issue tracking discussions from a while ago.

Essentially, I have the following Bootstrap Select input:

```
 <b-form-text id="countrySelectionHelp" class="text-white my-1">Country: <span class="text-danger">*</span></b-form-text>
 <b-form-select id="countrySelection" v-on:change="countryCountyConfiguration" v-model="selectedCountry" size="sm" aria-describedby="countrySelectionHelp" required>
   <option :value="null">Please select an option...</option>
   <option v-for="country in countrySelections" :value="country.value" :key="country.value">{{ country.name }}</option>
 </b-form-select>
```

Firstly, excuse the mix of v- and : binding syntax. Secondly, the on-change binding is triggering the countryCountyConfiguration function, I have stripped it back to its simplest form for ease of debugging:

```
...
    },
    countryCountyConfiguration() {
      console.log(this.selectedCountry);
    },
...
```

Effectively, the best was I can describe this issue is that `v-on:change="countryCountyConfiguration"` is always one step behind `v-model="selectedCountry"` ... always displaying the previous v-model binding. However, I really need the on change to feedback on country - such that if X country is chosen I will provide a dynamic choice of Counties and/or States.

I was wondering, how would I get `v-on:change="countryCountyConfiguration"` and `v-model="selectedCountry"` to work in conjunction?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, that should not happen. It seems to be a problem with the component. It would happen because `change` event is firing before the event which is responsible for `v-model`. By default `v-model` uses `:value` and `v-on:input` as value and event pair.

In your case, you should resort to explicit one-way data binding and avoid the use of `v-model` as:

```
<b-form-select v-on:change="countryCountyConfiguration($event)" :value="selectedCountry">
    <!-- Some other code -->
</b-form-select>
```

Your `countryCountyConfiguration` will be:

```
countryCountyConfiguration(newSelectedCountry) {
    // THIS IS IMPORTANT
    this.selectedCountry = newSelectedCountry;
    // DO REST OF THE STUFF HERE
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Should be noted that you can simply call `v-on:change="countryCountyConfiguration"` since `b-form-select` sends the new value by default, regardless of what argument you put in there, or even no argument. Even if you pass `$event` as an argument it doesn't send the actual event. Unfortunately it doesn't seem there's a way to access the actual event with `b-form-select`. A very odd choice by the developers.

Answer (score 0):

what about do it like this

```js
countryCountyConfiguration() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    //selectedCountry must be in 'v-model'
    console.log(selectedCountry)
  });
}
```

using '$nextTick'..